# Mapping a composite table to a table of default values in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've got a simple structure in database:

```
CREATE TABLE user_categories (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    category_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, category_id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_defaults (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    category_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id, category_id) REFERENCES user_categories (user_id, category_id)
);
```

The intention here is that user has a set of categories assigned and there's a table with defaults table (which could potentially have other columns)

However I struggle to map this to EF Core, I always end up getting extra columns in `user_categories` table.

My `UserCategory` class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EMMA.Authorization.Domain.Entities
{
    public class UserCategory
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }    
        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
        public User User { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        public UserDefaults UserDefaults { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`UserDefaults`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EMMA.Authorization.Domain.Entities
{
    public class UserDefaults
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserCategory> UserCategories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

That's `OnModelCreating` method that should configure relationships:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserCategory>().HasKey(s => new { s.UserId, s.CategoryId });
modelBuilder.Entity<UserDefaults>().HasKey(s => s.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserDefaults>()
    .HasMany(s => s.UserCategories)
    .WithOne(s => s.UserDefaults)
    .HasForeignKey(s => new { s.UserId, s.CategoryId })
    .IsRequired();
```

However that's the exception I'm getting when I try to create a migration:

> The relationship from 'UserCategory.UserDefaults' to 'UserDefaults.UserCategories' with foreign key properties {'UserId' : int, 'CategoryId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'UserId' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

How could I configure such an relationship in EF Core as shown in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually realized that I did declare a wrong relationship, it's not one to many, but rather one to one. Declaring the following mapping works as expected:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserCategory>()
    .HasOne(s => s.UserDefaults)
    .WithOne(s => s.UserCategory)
    .HasForeignKey<UserDefaults>(s => new { s.UserId, s.CategoryId })
    .IsRequired();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `user_catagories` object should have a composite key. You are already impliying this by having the FK from the other table be a composite key on the first. EF complains because this is actually not true. You can fix it by annotating both members as primary like so:

```
public class UserCatagory
{
      [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
      public int UserId { get; set; }

      [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
      public int CategoryId { get; set; }

      // Etc...
}
```

Comment: Hello, it has a composite key. `modelBuilder.Entity<UserCategory>().HasKey(s => new { s.UserId, s.CategoryId });`